# Customizing Ubuntu Mini Remix

Tags: customization, ubuntu-minimal

I've been using Ubuntu for 2 years and now I want to make my own. I just decided to get the Ubuntu minimal iso for the core of my custom Distro ... but everything seems so confusing!!! could anyone give me some help about how to start and add some packages and X, a good documentation could help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [This](http://www.ehow.com/info_12080100_ubuntu-mini-remix.html) and also [This](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal)

To download Ubuntu Mini Remix 12.04 [Click Here](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/)

> Customization
>
> To modify Ubuntu Mini Remix, download a customization utility, such as
>   UCK, Customizer or Reconstructor. UCK and Customizer are free,
>   open-source disk image customizers, while Reconstructor costs $5 for
>   unlimited use, as of September 2011. These programs work by extracting
>   the contents of the live CD, then allowing you to add programs and
>   other information. When you finish, the customization utility repacks
>   the live CD, allowing you to run Ubuntu Mini Remix directly from it or
>   install the OS to your computer.

<sup>Source: http://www.ehow.com/info_12080100_ubuntu-mini-remix.html</sup>

Comment: Thanks for help , i should install the customization utility on another os than the "mini remix", am i right? and one other ... if i add a package to the iso , will it be run as default when i run the iso live?!! what about a desktop?!! ( i want to use LXDE for my customization )

Comment: If you are planning to use UCK GUI, then yes. LXDE is a good choice.

Comment: i'm now in uck , it only gives me options Gnome , KDE and other! how can i determine the LXDE , also how to add a package!

Comment: Choose other, and you can install LXDE and other packages from terminal using the sudo apt-get install command.