# How to build my custom Ubuntu using Minimal CD

Tags: software-recommendation, customization, ubuntu-minimal, custom-distributions

I have downloaded the 30 mb minimal Ubuntu 12.04 iso file. I would like to customize it. I would like o have the following customizations:

1. add Ubuntu desktop GUI with Unity.
2. add essential software and applications, including network.
3. add other software
4. And above all, I need to install my own kernel.
5. I need to change the background images, logos and themes.
6. Is it possible to change the boot animation ?

How is it possible?
Will Ubuntu Customization Kit work ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/141762/customizing-ubuntu-mini-remix/141773#141773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 30MB minimal ISO `mini.iso` is NOT a minimal Live-CD; it's a minimal **net-install** CD, and I don't think it's possible to customize it in the way you want. You need to start with a minimal Live-CD such as Ubuntu Mini Remix, which can be customized using the Ubuntu Customization Kit and other utilities. Please see [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/141773/58612) from @Mitch to a similar question for a how-to.

Comment: izx, I read that post, and was helpful.
I have read somewhere that, when making the live cd, it is also possible to change the prompt like "ubunut@ubuntu" to "user@something" .

How is that possible ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge `gksu gedit /etc/hostname` and 
`gksu gedit /etc/hosts`

Comment: @virpara I actually meant to edit the user and host of the live cd and not of the Ubuntu installed in my machine.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge these are the files you need to edit weather you want to change on current installation or if you are building custom `.squashfs`.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge: that's what he meant -- I don't know about the tools used to remaster, but using the "bare" way of remastering, i.e. modifying the `.squashfs` after `chroot`ing into it, that's the way you do it.